# Python - Split function returns one value instead of expected two

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a database API in order to get a better grasp of how APIs work. Currently fixing the errors and whatnot, when I tried the `delete` function (Option 3), it gives me an error and tells me that the `split` function is returning one value rather than two.

My guess is that it's either reading the lines incorrectly, or through reading the text file, it doesn't register the tab (`'\t'`) but rather as a space (`' '`) at times.

I'm doing this through VS Code, not sure if that's a contributing factor at all with the indents and stuff. But I've got it at 4 spaces = tab like the Python IDLE does normally.

Here's the code:

```
import time

def add(filename):
    print('Name?')
    key = input()
    print('Phone number?')
    value = input()
    f = open(filename, "a")
    f.write(key + "\t" + value + "\n")
    f.close()

def find(filename, key):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    for line in f:
        #first stores the current key in variable
        (currentKey, currentValue) = line.split('\t', 1)
        if currentKey == key:
            return currentValue[:-1]
    f.close()

def delete(filename, key):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    f1 = open('temporary.txt', "w")
    for (line) in f:
        #Error occurs here
        (currentKey, currentValue) = line.split('\t', 1)
        if currentKey != key:
            f1.write(line)
    f.close()
    f1.close()
    import os
    os.replace('temporary.txt', filename)
    

def update(filename, key, value):
    resultfile = "temporary.txt"
    f = open(filename, "r")
    f1 = open(resultfile, "w")
    for line in filename:
        (currentKey, currentValue) = line.split('\t', 1)
        if currentKey != key:
            f1.write(line)
        else:
            f1.write(currentKey + '\t' + value + '\n')
    f.close()
    f1.close()
    import os
    os.replace(resultfile, filename)

filename = 'telephone.txt'

#Current Menu Interface
def menu():
    print("Welcome to the telephone directory")
    print("Your options are:")
    print()
    print("1) Adding")
    print("2) Finding")
    print("3) Deleting")
    print("4) Updating")
    print("5) Quitting")
    choice = input()
    return choice

#actual decision code
def decision(choice):
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        if choice == '1':
            add(filename)
            choice = menu()
        elif choice == '2':
            print("What is the name of the person you are looking for?")
            key = input()
            value = find(filename, key)
            print(key + "'s phone number is: " + value)
            choice = menu()
        elif choice == '3':
            print("What is the name of the person you are looking to delete from the directory?")
            key = input()
            delete(filename, key)
            choice = menu()
        elif choice == '4':
            print("What is the name of the person?")
            key = input()
            print("What is the telephone number you want to replace it with?")
            value = input()
            update(filename, key, value)
            choice = menu()
        elif choice == '5':
            print("Thank you for using the program! Your file contents are stored in a file called 'telephone.txt'.")
            time.sleep(1)
            loop = 0
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from 1 to 5. No spaces at all.")
            choice = menu()

choice = menu()
decision(choice)
```

Comment: can you print the value of `line` before using `split`

Comment: Upvote and mark it as answer if the answer below solves your problem

Comment: Yeah, I just commented on that answer. Unfortunately, I wished that was the only mistake I committed but it seems to not be the case.
As for printing the value of `line`, the code is able to find the correct `line` accordingly. It prints out the `key` (a name in this case), a significant `\t` in between and a `value` (a number in this case).

Comment: if your separator could be tab or space, you could just use `line.split(None,1)`

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `None` value? In my file I've always set the `'/t'` value as the separator. But it seems like a space value in the txt file itself because of the way tabbing works.

Comment: The `None` is a placeholder, because the split char is a positional argument. Doing `line.split(1)` will raise an error, because `1` is not a `str`, and you're missing the split char. If it's `None` it will default to any whitespace

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the string `filename`, not the file handle:

```py
def delete(filename, key):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    f1 = open('temporary.txt', "w")
    for (line) in filename: # here
        ...
```

Which means that you are getting each character in `filename`. So if `filename` is `'hello.txt'`, you'd get:

```py
h
e
l
l
o
.
t
x
t
```

You should be doing

```py
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    # rest of loop
```

Or, rather:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # rest of loop
```

Last, if your lines do not contain a tab, `str.split('\t')` will return a single-element list, so you could do:

```py
try:
    a, b = line.split('\t', 1)
except ValueError:
    print('No tab in line')
    continue # skip the line
```

Alternatively, you could `raise` if you want the program to stop

```py
try:
    a, b = line.split('\t', 1)
except ValueError:
    print('No tab in line')
    raise # stop the program
```

Last, the best way to handle either tabs *or* spaces would be the way that @RufusVS suggested:

```py
try:
    a, b = line.split(None, 1)
except ValueError:
   # either raise or continue
   print('Line doesn't contain a whitespace separator')
   continue
```

Where `str.split` gets passed `None` because the function is expecting a separator argument, and omitting it will raise an error:

```py
x = 'abc def'

x.split(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str or None, not int

x.split(None, 1)
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: Good point, I just changed my code so it reflects that, but I still get the same error nonetheless.

Comment: As it turns out, I must've tampered the .txt file directly because once I deleted my previous entries it worked perfectly fine. But thank you for writing out an elaborate explanation of possible errors I have made along the way! You have earned my upvote and check mark.